# XAML Telerik DataGrids cause page to be cut off on low resolution and non-full screen windows?

Tags: c#, xaml, browser, telerik, radgridview

I appreciate you taking the time to help me with this itch...

As it shows in the code below I have Telerik DataGrids. When the window is restored down it simply cuts the middle of the grid and wont let you scroll on the page or on the datagrid. page's grids and borders should adjust to the height of the users browser. and insert scroll bars automatically as need.

I have this same approach implemented on other pages and it works fine, this page however is being stubborn.

Again, thank you in advance for your help and time!

<---CODE BELOW--->

```
<controls:ViewBase
xmlns:telerik="http://schemas.telerik.com/2008/xaml/presentation" 
x:Class="CS.Sentry.Silverlight.Module.DataSetup.UpdatePrice.UpdatePriceView"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:CS.Sentry.Silverlight.Library.Controls;assembly=Library" 
xmlns:GenericComponents="clr-namespace:CS.Sentry.Silverlight.ComponentLibraries.GenericComponents;assembly=GenericComponents"
xmlns:cal="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Practices.Composite.Presentation.Commands;assembly=Microsoft.Practices.Composite.Presentation" 
xmlns:data="clr-namespace:CS.Sentry.Library.Controls.Data;assembly=Library.Controls"       
xmlns:CustomControls="clr-namespace:CS.Sentry.Library.Controls.CustomControls;assembly=Library.Controls" 
xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:CS.Sentry.Library.Controls;assembly=Library.Controls" 
xmlns:CArt_Layout="clr-namespace:ComponentArt.Silverlight.UI.Layout;assembly=ComponentArt.Silverlight.UI.Layout"
xmlns:Controls1="clr-namespace:Telerik.Windows.Controls;assembly=Telerik.Windows.Controls.GridView">

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Margin="0,1,0,0">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <!--Header-->
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <!--Data Tables-->
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <!--Header-->
    <Border Grid.Row="0" Margin="0,0,0,0" Style="{StaticResource borderStyle}">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <!--Column Zero-->
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                <!--Column One-->
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <!--Row Zero-->
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <!--Row One-->
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <!--Row Two-->
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <!--StackPanel-->
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Margin="5,5,0,5" >
                <Controls:CustomRadioButton  Margin="0,2,0,0" Width="80" Content="Held"  VerticalAlignment="Center" IsChecked="{Binding IsHeldChecked,Mode=TwoWay}"  GroupName="PriceType"></Controls:CustomRadioButton>
                <GenericComponents:GenericPicker x:Name="Selector" Margin="0,0,10,0"  AsOfDate ="{Binding AsOfDate, Mode=TwoWay}"  FilterType="Filter"  Title ="Select" SelectedItems ="{Binding Selected, Mode=TwoWay}" ></GenericComponents:GenericPicker>
                <RadioButton  x:Name="RadioButton1" Content="First" VerticalAlignment="Center" GroupName="Group" IsChecked="{Binding First, Mode=TwoWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,2,3,1"></RadioButton>
                <RadioButton  x:Name="RadioButton2" Content="Second" VerticalAlignment="Center" GroupName="Group" IsChecked="{Binding Second,Mode=TwoWay}"  HorizontalAlignment="Center"></RadioButton>
            </StackPanel>

            <!--StackPanel-->
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Margin="5,5,0,2" x:Name="SelectedPanel">
                <Controls:CustomRadioButton  Margin="0,2,0,0" Width="80" Content="Selected" VerticalAlignment="Center" GroupName="Type" IsChecked="{Binding IsSelectedChecked,Mode=TwoWay}"></Controls:CustomRadioButton>
                <GenericComponents:GenericPicker x:Name="Selector" Margin="0,0,10,0"  AsOfDate ="{Binding AsOfDate, Mode=TwoWay}"  FilterType="Filter"  Title ="Select" SelectedItems ="{Binding Selected, Mode=TwoWay}" ></GenericComponents:GenericPicker>
            </StackPanel>

            <!--Date Range-->
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Margin="15,5,0,2" Grid.RowSpan="2">
                <CustomControls:GenericCalendarControl IsRange="False" Margin="10,0,0,0"
                                            SelectedDateMnemonic="{Binding AsOfDateMnemonic, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                            SelectedEndDate="{Binding AsOfDate, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
            </StackPanel>

            <!--Refresh/Authority-->
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="2"  Margin="5,5,0,5" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
                <Button x:Name="refreshButton"  Content="Refresh" Margin="3,0,3,0" Height="25"  Width="120"   cal:Click.Command="{Binding RefreshCommand}"  ></Button>
                <TextBlock Text="Text1: " Style="{StaticResource textBlockStyle}" Width="120"  Margin="30,1,0,0"></TextBlock>
                <ComboBox VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" ItemsSource="{Binding Items,Mode=TwoWay}" DisplayMemberPath="Name"  Height="22" Width="200"  Margin="0,1,20,0" SelectedItem ="{Binding Item,Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                <Controls:CustomButton VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="21" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Content="Field Chooser"
                                       cal:Click.Command="{Binding FieldChooserCommand}"
                                       ToolTipService.ToolTip="Select additional fields">                        
                </Controls:CustomButton>
                <Controls:CustomCheckBox VerticalAlignment="Center" Content="Ignore Overrides" IsChecked="{Binding IgnoreOverrides,Mode=TwoWay}" Margin="20,1,20,0" ToolTipService.ToolTip="Override"/>
                <Controls:CustomButton VerticalAlignment="Center"  Height="21" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Content="View Overrides"  Click="ViewOverrides_Click"/>
                <Controls:CustomButton x:Name="Update"  VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="10"  Height="21" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Content="Download"  cal:Click.Command="{Binding Command}" 
                                       Visibility="Collapsed"  ToolTipService.ToolTip="Downloads"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </Border>

    <!--Data Tables-->
    <Border Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,0,0,0" Style="{StaticResource borderStyle}" VerticalAlignment="Top">

        <!--Side By Side Grids-->
        <Grid Grid.Row="0">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <!--Grid One-->
                <ColumnDefinition Width="0.59*"></ColumnDefinition>
                <!--Splitter-->
                <ColumnDefinition Width="0.02*"></ColumnDefinition>
                <!--Grid Two-->
                <ColumnDefinition Width="0.39*"></ColumnDefinition>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <!--Grid One, Splitter, Grid Two-->
                <RowDefinition Height="0.925*" />
                <!--Footer-->
                <RowDefinition Height="0.075*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <!--Grid One-->
            <Grid Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">

                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <!--Grid-->
                    <RowDefinition Height="0.95*" />
                    <!--Label/Buttons-->
                    <RowDefinition Height="0.05*" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <!--Grid-->
                <data:CustomDataGrid Grid.Row="0" Margin="5,16,0,5" ShowGroupPanel="False" VerticalAlignment="Top" x:Name="priceDatagrid" Background="Transparent" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                            ItemsSource="{Binding info,Mode=TwoWay}"   IsReadOnly="False"  SelectedItem="{Binding infoItem,Mode=TwoWay}"  
                            CanUserFreezeColumns="False" CanUserResizeColumns="True" CanUserReorderColumns="False" IsFilteringAllowed="False" ScrollMode="RealTime" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch">
                    <Controls1:RadGridView.Columns>
                        <Controls1:GridViewDataColumn Header="Col1" DataMemberBinding="{Binding ID, Mode=TwoWay}" IsReadOnly="True" Width="45"/>
                        <Controls1:GridViewDataColumn Header="Col2" DataMemberBinding="{Binding Name, Mode=TwoWay}" IsReadOnly="True" Width="100"/>
                        <Controls1:GridViewDataColumn Header="Col3" DataMemberBinding="{Binding Scheme, Mode=TwoWay}" IsReadOnly="True" Width="60"/>
                        <Controls1:GridViewDataColumn Header="Col4" DataMemberBinding="{Binding Default, Mode=TwoWay}" IsReadOnly="True" Width="105"/>
                        <Controls1:GridViewDataColumn Header="Col5" UniqueName="Date"  DataMemberBinding="{Binding AsOfDate, Mode=TwoWay}" IsReadOnly="True" Width="105"/>
                        <Controls1:GridViewDataColumn Header="Col6" TextAlignment="Right" Width="70" DataMemberBinding="{Binding Price, Converter={StaticResource mathValueConverter}, ConverterParameter=6, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                        <Controls1:GridViewDataColumn Header="Col7" UniqueName="Spread" TextAlignment="Right" Width="70" DataMemberBinding="{Binding Spread, Converter={StaticResource mathValueConverter}, ConverterParameter=6, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                        <Controls1:GridViewDataColumn Header="Col8" UniqueName="Bid" TextAlignment="Right" Width="70" DataMemberBinding="{Binding Bid, Converter={StaticResource mathValueConverter}, ConverterParameter=6, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                        <Controls1:GridViewDataColumn Header="Col9" UniqueName="Ask" TextAlignment="Right" Width="70" DataMemberBinding="{Binding Ask, Converter={StaticResource mathValueConverter}, ConverterParameter=6, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                        <Controls1:GridViewDataColumn Header="Col10" UniqueName="Depth" TextAlignment="Right" Width="50" DataMemberBinding="{Binding Depth, Converter={StaticResource mathValueConverter}, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                        <Controls1:GridViewDataColumn Header="Col11" UniqueName="Volume" TextAlignment="Right" Width="120" DataMemberBinding="{Binding Volume, Converter={StaticResource mathValueConverter}, ConverterParameter=2, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                        <Controls1:GridViewDataColumn Header="Col12" UniqueName="Outstanding" TextAlignment="Right" Width="120" DataMemberBinding="{Binding Outstanding, Converter={StaticResource mathValueConverter}, ConverterParameter=2, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                        <Controls1:GridViewDataColumn Header="Col13" UniqueName="Currency" TextAlignment="Left" Width="60" DataMemberBinding="{Binding Currency, Mode=TwoWay}"  IsReadOnly="True" />
                        <Controls1:GridViewDataColumn Header="Col14" DataMemberBinding="{Binding Notes, Mode=TwoWay}" Width="180"/>
                    </Controls1:RadGridView.Columns>
                </data:CustomDataGrid>

                <!--Import/Export Buttons-->
                <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="5,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                    <Button x:Name="exportButton" Padding="5" Content="Export" Height="25" Width="70" Margin="3,1,3,1" cal:Click.Command="{Binding ExportCommand}" ></Button>
                    <Button x:Name="importButton" Padding="5" Content="Import" Height="25" Width="70" Margin="3,1,3,1" cal:Click.Command="{Binding ImportFileCommand}" ></Button>
                </StackPanel>

                <!--Info Label-->
                <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="5,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                    <TextBlock x:Name="InformationLabel"  Width ="500" Foreground="#FF15428B" Text="Prices in this grid will be updated as-of the date selected at the top of the screen.  Sentry will not use the Prior Pricing Date. The Prior Pricing Date is informational only." Height="30" Margin="3,1,3,1" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="10"></TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>

            <Grid Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1">
                <!--Splitter to expand/compress-->
                <CArt_Layout:Splitter CollapseDirection="Right" ShowsPreview="False" x:Name="ySplitter"  Background="Transparent"></CArt_Layout:Splitter>
            </Grid>

            <Grid Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2">
                <!--Grid Two-->
                <telerik:GroupBox Header="History"  x:Name="PriceGroupBox"   Margin="0" VerticalAlignment="Top"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" >

                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <!--Menu-->
                            <RowDefinition Height="0.05*"/>
                            <!--Grid-->
                            <RowDefinition Height="0.8*" />
                            <!--Pager-->
                            <RowDefinition Height="0.05*"/>
                            <!--Buttons-->
                            <RowDefinition Height="0.05*"/>
                            <!--Footer-->
                            <RowDefinition Height="0.05*"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                        <!--Menu-->
                        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Margin="0"  x:Name="proxyOverrideMsgTextBlock" Style="{StaticResource textBlockStyle}" Text="{Binding ProxyOverrideMsg}" Visibility="{Binding ProxyOverrideMsgVisibility}"  TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top"    />

                        <!--Grid-->
                        <data:CustomDataGrid Grid.Row="1" Margin="0" ShowGroupPanel="False"  x:Name="Datagrid" Background="Transparent" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                                    ItemsSource="{Binding PriceInfos,Mode=TwoWay}"  SelectedItem="{Binding PriceInfo,Mode=TwoWay}"   IsReadOnly="False"  VerticalAlignment="Top"   
                                    CanUserFreezeColumns="False" CanUserResizeColumns="True"  CanUserReorderColumns="False" IsFilteringAllowed="False" ScrollMode="RealTime" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch">

                            <Controls1:RadGridView.Columns>
                                <Controls1:GridViewDataColumn Header="Date" UniqueName="Date"  DataMemberBinding="{Binding AsOfDate, Mode=TwoWay}" IsReadOnly="False" Width="75"/>
                                <Controls1:GridViewDataColumn Header="Value" TextAlignment="Right" Width="70" DataMemberBinding="{Binding Price, Converter={StaticResource mathValueConverter}, ConverterParameter=6, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                                <Controls1:GridViewDataColumn Header="Spread" UniqueName="Spread" TextAlignment="Right" Width="70" DataMemberBinding="{Binding Spread, Converter={StaticResource mathValueConverter}, ConverterParameter=6, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                                <Controls1:GridViewDataColumn Header="Bid" UniqueName="Bid" TextAlignment="Right" Width="70" DataMemberBinding="{Binding Bid, Converter={StaticResource mathValueConverter}, ConverterParameter=6, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                                <Controls1:GridViewDataColumn Header="Ask" UniqueName="Ask" TextAlignment="Right" Width="70" DataMemberBinding="{Binding Ask, Converter={StaticResource mathValueConverter}, ConverterParameter=6, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                                <Controls1:GridViewDataColumn Header="Depth" UniqueName="Depth" TextAlignment="Right" Width="50" DataMemberBinding="{Binding Depth, Converter={StaticResource mathValueConverter}, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                                <Controls1:GridViewDataColumn Header="Volume" UniqueName="Volume" TextAlignment="Right" Width="120" DataMemberBinding="{Binding Volume, Converter={StaticResource mathValueConverter}, ConverterParameter=2, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                                <Controls1:GridViewDataColumn Header="Outstanding" UniqueName="Outstanding" TextAlignment="Right" Width="120" DataMemberBinding="{Binding Outstanding, Converter={StaticResource mathValueConverter}, ConverterParameter=2, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                                <Controls1:GridViewDataColumn Header="Currency" UniqueName="Currency" TextAlignment="Left" Width="60" DataMemberBinding="{Binding Currency, Mode=TwoWay}"  IsReadOnly="True" />
                                <Controls1:GridViewDataColumn Header="Notes" DataMemberBinding="{Binding Notes, Mode=TwoWay}" Width="80"/>
                                <Controls1:GridViewDataColumn Header="Update User" DataMemberBinding="{Binding UpdateUser, Mode=TwoWay}" IsReadOnly="True" Width="80"/>
                                <Controls1:GridViewDataColumn Header="Update Date"  UniqueName="Update Date" DataMemberBinding="{Binding UpdateDate, Mode=TwoWay}" IsReadOnly="True" Width="130"/>
                            </Controls1:RadGridView.Columns>
                        </data:CustomDataGrid>

                        <!--Pager-->
                        <telerik:RadDataPager Grid.Row="2" x:Name="datagridPager"  PageSize="20" Margin="0,0,5,0" Visibility="{Binding DataGridVisibility,Mode=TwoWay}" Source="{Binding Items, ElementName=Datagrid, Mode=TwoWay}"  DisplayMode="All"  AutoEllipsisMode="Both" NumericButtonCount="10" IsTotalItemCountFixed="True"/>

                        <!--Add/Remove/Export Buttons-->
                        <Grid Grid.Row="3" Margin="0,2,0,0"  >
                            <telerik:RadButton x:Name="addButton"  Content="+" Margin="0,1,0,1" Height="25" Width="40" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  cal:Click.Command="{Binding AddCommand, Mode=TwoWay}"></telerik:RadButton>
                            <Button x:Name="removeButton"  Content="-" Margin="45,1,0,1" Height="25" Width="40" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  cal:Click.Command="{Binding RemoveCommand, Mode=TwoWay}"></Button>
                            <Button x:Name="exportButton"  Content="Export" Margin="10,1,5,1" Height="25" Width="70" HorizontalAlignment="Right"  cal:Click.Command="{Binding ExportCommand, Mode=TwoWay}"></Button>
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                </telerik:GroupBox>
            </Grid>

            <!--Footer-->
            <Grid  Grid.Row="1"  Grid.Column="0" ColumnSpan="3">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="5,10,8,10" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                    <Button x:Name="SaveButton"  Content="Save" Margin="0,1,0,1" Height="25" Width="70" HorizontalAlignment="Right"  Click="SaveButton_Click"></Button>
                    <Button x:Name="CancelButton"  Content="Cancel" Margin="10,1,0,1" Height="25" Width="70" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Click="CancelButton_Click" ></Button>
                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the VerticalAlignment of data:CustomDataGrid to "Stretch"